# ¿Como obtener el valor de views que han sido "infladas"?

Tags: android

Buenas, tengo  un problema  y he estado investigando  y no he encontrado solución  , el problema es el siguiente , al querer obtener el valor de un edittext que he agregado dinamicamente se detiene mi aplicacion y me muetra el siguiente error

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference`

y el siguiente código es donde es el que use para aparecer las vistas

```
 private void agregarSpinner(View view){        
    View infla = View.inflate(getActivity(),R.layout.nuevos_spinner_materiales,layout);        
    Spinner spinnerMateriales2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinnerMateriales2.setAdapter(adapter);      

}
```

y  al leer el error me  doy cuenta del problema , lo que pasa que no se como inicializar las vistas que agregue para obtener su valor

Comment: Tu problema no esta en el `inflate`, sino en una parte del codigo donde estas asignado un texto a un `EditText`. Intenta identificar esa porcion del codigo y ver porque esta null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si inflas un componente dinámicamente, tienes que usar el componente padre que inflaste para traer la referencia de los childs.

Por ejemplo, si realizaste el inflate de la siguiente manera:

```
 View infla = View.inflate(getActivity(),R.layout.nuevos_spinner_materiales,layout);
```

Y tratas de obtener la referencia del componente child de la siguiente forma:

```
 private void agregarSpinner(View view){               
    Spinner spinnerMateriales2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
}
```

Podrías obtener un error, si spinner2, estaba dentro de "nuevos_spinner_materiales", lo que debería hacer sería de la siguiente manera:

```
 private void agregarSpinner(View view){      
 View infla = View.inflate(getActivity(),R.layout.nuevos_spinner_materiales,layout);            
    Spinner spinnerMateriales2 = (Spinner) infla.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
}
```

Comment: @diegodeveloper  Muchas gracias!!!  si era por eso que no me funcionaba, saludos desde mexio